# pandas.to_datetime() returning different dtypes for columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm reading a table from CSV in to a dataframe `bar` and it has the following columns that are datetimes represented as strings

```
time_cols = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'gcreated_at', 'gupdated_at', 'deleted_at']
```

which I change to datetime with

```
for x in time_cols:
    bar[x] = pd.to_datetime(bar[x])
```

then I tried to do some date diff functions and ran in to trouble and so I checked the dtype for each of the columns and found

```
for col in time_cols:
    print col + " " + str(bar[col].dtype) + "\n"


created_at datetime64[ns]

updated_at datetime64[ns]

gcreated_at object

gupdated_at object

deleted_at datetime64[ns]
```

per another question on s/o I also tried

```
bar.convert_objects(convert_dates='coerce',convert_numeric=True)
```

but still have the mismatched data types

How can I force those `object` dtypes into `datetime64[ns]` types?

```
created_at  updated_at  gcreated_at gupdated_at
2014-03-26 12:13:34 2014-03-30 01:11:09 2015-07-09 18:40:04.0   2015-07-09 18:40:04.0
2014-03-31 21:40:24 2014-04-02 07:58:11 2014-04-02 07:59:36.0   2014-04-02 07:59:36.0
2014-05-23 23:32:59 2014-05-25 05:52:56 2014-08-21 17:05:01.0   2014-08-21 17:05:01.0
```

Comment: Are you sure `gcreated_at` and `gupdated_at` are `datetime` castable? Can you show `bar.head(5)` if the data isn't sensitive?

Comment: Sorry -- unsure how to format it nicely, but added to the main Q

Upon seeing it printed out clearly, I'm thinking that the issue may arise from `.0` being appended to the g... times

Comment: That's the only problem I can think of. Try removing the trailing `.` and `0` and re-run the code?